next js error with liveblocks and yjs and cloudfare/firebase
I tried to make a yjs blockNote with liveblocks as provider but I have a problem that when the block note appear in the page the data not fetching so the block note looks blank and when I make any modification in code the error below appears, this problem appears from nothing the code was working until this error happened can any one help me fix it :
function BlockNote({doc, provider, darkMode} : EditorProps) {
    
    const userInfo  = useSelf((me) => me.info)
    const editor : BlockNoteEditor = useCreateBlockNote({
        collaboration: {
            provider,
            fragment: doc.getXmlFragment("document-store"),
            user : {
                name: userInfo?.name,
                color: "yellow",
            }
            
        },
    })
    console.log("YXmlFragment : ", doc.getXmlFragment("document-store"));
    console.log("editor : ",editor)
    return (
        <div className='relative max-w-6xl mx-auto'>
            <BlockNoteView  className='min-h-screen' editor={editor} theme={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"}/>
        </div>
    )
}


function Editor() {
    const room = useRoom();
    const [doc, setDoc] = useState<Y.Doc>()
    const [provider, setProvider] = useState<LiveblocksYjsProvider>();
    const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        const yDoc = new Y.Doc();
        const yProvider = new LiveblocksYjsProvider(room, yDoc)
        
        setDoc(yDoc);
        setProvider(yProvider);

        return () => {
            yDoc?.destroy();
            yProvider?.destroy();

        }
    }, [room])

    if(!doc || !provider){
        return null;
    }

    const style = `hover:white ${
        darkMode 
        ? "text-gray-300 bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover-text-gray-700"
        : "text-gray-700 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 hover-text-gray-700"

    }`

  return (
    <div className='max-w-6xl mx-auto'>
        <BlockNote doc={doc} provider={provider} darkMode={darkMode} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Editor

the auto load is not working, also when I change something in code this error apears :
TypeError: el.toArray is not a function
    at createNodeFromYElement (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b029f9._.js:13416:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b029f9._.js:13213:66
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b029f9._.js:13213:57
    at ProsemirrorBinding.mux (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_lib0_b97fb5._.js:3264:17)
    at ProsemirrorBinding._forceRerender (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b029f9._.js:13208:14)
    at Object.view (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_b029f9._.js:13059:25)
    at EditorView.updatePluginViews (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_prosemirror-view_dist_index_212d9a.js:4895:73)
    at EditorView.updateStateInner (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_prosemirror-view_dist_index_212d9a.js:4859:14)
    at EditorView.updateState (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_prosemirror-view_dist_index_212d9a.js:4795:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/node_modules_@blocknote_core_dist_blocknote_252cd1.js:10648:23

also this what the console contains :
the editor in console
